# Â infront of £ with ANSI encoding and PHP error with UTF-8

Tags: php, session, encoding, utf-8

I am passing some variables from one page to another using $_SESSION.

When I have encoding set to ANSI I get the Â symbol wherever a £ sign appears.
If I switch to UTF-8, the problem disappears, but I get the following PHP error:

> **Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/me/public_html/path/order.php:1) in /home/me/public_html/path/order.php on line 2**

My code is as follows:

```
session_start();
$price = $_SESSION['get_price'];
```

Comment: Your error suggests that you are already outputting HTTP heads prior to this point.  So, you need to consider your code prior to session_start().

Comment: There is nothing else on that page other than the code above.

Comment: Is order.php:1 your <?php line and, if so, have you checked to see (possibly in a hex editor) that you've no extra characters at the start?  E.g. checking for a BOM (byte-order-mark).

Comment: Yeah, line 1 is <?php - There are no other characters on there at all. :S could it be something to do with the first page that parsed the vars? Or is that irrelevant?

Comment: The only relevant thing should be what is output by this page.  Can I verify - have you checked in a hex editor (or similar) that there's nothing before the <?php.  The BOM will be invisible if you just look in a normal editor etc...

Comment: Fixed it, my bad. You were right about the BOM. Thanks!

Comment: A BOM would be invisible if viewed in UTF-8 display mode. It should be visible if viewed in Latin-1, Windows-1252, etc. encodings as 3 odd characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an (invisible) BOM (byte-order-mark) that has been placed by your editor at the start of the file.  It is being output before `session_start()` thus making your page unable to change the HTTP headers.  Remove the BOM and the problem will go away.